# Timeout during running linq query with entityframework to postgresql

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a query that running on postgresql server and I have translated this sql query to linq. The problem is  when I am running this linq query in my Api I get timeout error because of it takes so long to retrieve results. I don't understand the reason; the sql query takes milliseconds on server with postgresql but with linq query in api it takes so long and finally throw error.

This is the main postgresql query:

```
SELECT  b.mandant, b.bk, b.gjahr, Sum(b.betrag_hw) AS bewegungen_ohne_stdpos, Count(DISTINCT b.konto) 
AS anzahl_konten_ohne_stdpos  
FROM   mv_buchungsstatistik b
left join stdpos_konto k on b.mandant = k.mandant AND b.gjahr = k.gjahr AND b.bk = k.bk  
AND b.konto = k.konto
WHERE  b.mandant = 1 AND b.gjahr = 2019 AND b.bk = '0001'   and k.id is null
group by b.mandant, b.bk, b.gjahr
```

this takes 340 milliseconds.

This is the equivalent linq query :

```
(from f in DbContext.MvBuchungsstatistik
 from k in DbContext.stdpos_konto.Where(p => p.mandant == f.mandant && p.bk == f.bk 
 && p.gjahr == f.gjahr && p.konto == f.konto).DefaultIfEmpty()
 where f.mandant == 1 && f.bk == "0001" && f.gjahr == 2019 && k.id == null
 group f by new { f.mandant, f.bk, f.gjahr } into grp
 select new AuditAgent
 {
    mandant = grp.Key.mandant,
    bk = grp.Key.bk,
    gjahr = grp.Key.gjahr,
    bewegungen_ohne_stdpos = grp.Sum(x => x.betrag_hw),
    anzahl_konten_ohne_stdpos = grp.Select(x => x.konto).Distinct().Count()
  });
```

And this get below timeout error:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

After some test I see when I comment out this part it works :

> grp.Select(x => x.konto).Distinct().Count()

--EDIT--
I did the left join in a way that more suggested.

```
  var test = from f in DbContext.MvBuchungsstatistik
                   join k in DbContext.stdpos_konto 
                   on new { f.mandant , f.bk,  f.gjahr, f.konto } equals new { mandant = k.mandant.Value, k.bk, gjahr = k.gjahr.Value, k.konto } 
                   into joinData
                   from results in joinData.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   where f.mandant == clientId && f.bk == companyCode && f.gjahr == businessYear && results.id == null
                   select new
                   {
                       f
                   };

        var testMitGrp = test.GroupBy(p => new { p.f.mandant, p.f.bk, p.f.gjahr }).Select(p => new
        {
            p.Key.mandant,
            p.Key.bk,
            p.Key.gjahr,
            bewegungen_ohne_stdpos = p.Sum(x => x.f.betrag_hw),
            anzahl_konten_ohne_stdpos = p.Select(x => x.f.konto).Distinct().Count()
        });
```

Nothing changed, even the first approach was faster than second one.  Fir approach took 34 seconds and second approach took 35 secons
-- END EDIT --

But why this effect like this? What is the problem and how I can improve the performance of query?

PC: I am using Entity Framework 6 (EF6) with [EntityFramework6.Npgsql](http://www.npgsql.org/ef6/) version 6.4.1

Comment: Your linq query is not equivalent to sql version. `from f in DbContext.MvBuchungsstatistik
 from k in DbContext.stdpos_konto.... ` means `cross join` instead of `left join`. For proper `join` statement, please see: [Perform left outer joins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins)

Comment: @MaciejLos the way I do is also left join, it is an easier way than proper notation that you use intos. I get correct result when I use query and increase timeout time dramatically.

Comment: I don't know much about PostgreSql, but it's not unlikely that it will optimize joins much better than equality in `Where`. It think you should at least give it a try.

Comment: @GertArnold I will give a try sure; but main problematic part is grp.Select(x => x.konto).Distinct().Count() , do you have an idea about it, it is just an extra count, how it increase query time more than 1000 times ?

Comment: Probably because it is translated as a subquery and not as `Count(DISTINCT...`. Check the generated query.